# Confirmation token can't be blank al intentar abrir confirmation/show despues de crear usuario

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy trabajando con device en rails y aunque sale el log de que se creó el usuario y de que salió el email no me logra entrar a la página a menos que le dé clic al log de rails c.

El log en cuestión:

```
    Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2022-11-04 00:43:54 -0400
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"ale12", "photo"=>"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633332755192-727a05c4013d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80", "email"=>"ale12@gmaikl.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  TRANSACTION (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "ale12@gmaikl.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "photo", "bio", "posts_counter", "created_at", "updated_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "unconfirmed_email") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "ale12"], ["photo", "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633332755192-727a05c4013d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=580&q=80"], ["bio", nil], ["posts_counter", 0], ["created_at", "2022-11-04 04:43:54.528291"], ["updated_at", "2022-11-04 04:43:54.528291"], ["email", "ale12@gmaikl.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$12$CajTEWpwnxfkWx3V/veepOG7SPvbKHzgaABUtLspjLji9F29PA1oS"], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["confirmation_token", "Fx1nzssm2mLdxVxbxzwy"], ["confirmed_at", nil], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2022-11-04 04:43:54.528429"], ["unconfirmed_email", nil]]
  TRANSACTION (3.0ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
  Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 159)
Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 2.5ms
Delivered mail 6364988a85fd7_29113c14870e@chino-pc.mail (281.2ms)
Date: Fri, 04 Nov 2022 00:43:54 -0400
From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
To: ale12@gmaikl.com
Message-ID: <6364988a85fd7_29113c14870e@chino-pc.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome ale12@gmaikl.com!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=Fx1nzssm2mLdxVxbxzwy">Confirm my account</a></p>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation
Completed 302 Found in 512ms (ActiveRecord: 4.3ms | Allocations: 23292)
```

Después de esto me redirige a la página de `users/confirmation` pero con el error del `Confirmation token can't be blank`. No tengo idea de por qué pasa eso. También he de aclarar que estoy utilizando una gema llamada `letter_opener` para este caso.

Esta es mi *routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "users#index"
  devise_for  :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations' }
  get '/user_confirmation' => 'confirmations#after_registration_path'

  resources :users do
    resources :posts, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show] do
      resources :comments, only: [:create]
      resources :likes, only: [:create]
    end
  end
end
```

También hay que aclarar que si le doy clic al link que sale en el log, todo funciona perfectamente.

esto es config/enviroment/development

```
    config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # change to true to allow email to be sent during development
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "mail.google.com",####important
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

Comment: tambien es byeno aclarar que en el routes el /user_confirmation es solo para probar si funcionaban las rutas customizadas pero tampoco me agarran

Comment: ¿y cómo tienes configurado letter_opener? ¿y si en vez de letter opener usas [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher#how) para ver si es que te llegan los correos? que ese ni siquiera tienes que ponerlo en tu Gemfile (aunque probablemente tendrás que desactivar letter_opener primero). Podrías agregar a tu pregunta tu configuración de `config/environments/development.rb` que quizás ahí esté el problema.

Comment: despues de un tiempo decidi tambien cambiar el letter oppener a usar el que normal mente se usa que seria esa gema ya paso ese archivo

Comment: ya fue agregado en la descripcion

Comment: ahora tengo un problema que se sale este error `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create` no tengo idea porque

Comment: hice unos cambio al `  config/environments/development.rb ` y hora tengo otro error SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name